# Traits with associated type in templates

Tags: rust

I have been having problems compiling my Rust code, I managed to boil down the issue to this snippet:

```
use std::slice::Iter;

pub trait Foo<'a> {
    type Bar: Iterator<Item=&'a usize>;

    fn make(&self) -> usize;
}

pub struct Juice;

impl <'a> Foo<'a> for Juice {
    type Bar = Iter<'a, usize>;

    fn make(&self) -> usize { 0us }
}


// Uncomment this line to break things
// fn get_int<'a, T: Foo<'a>>(t: T) -> usize {
//   t.make()
// }


fn main() {
    println!("Hello, {:?} world!" , Juice.make());
}
```

I am pretty sure I am just missing something, is there anything I need to do to make this trait work? I am using the latest nightly alpha build (at the time of writing):

```
rustc 1.0.0-nightly (458a6a2f6 2015-01-25 21:20:37 +0000)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you need to write this:

```
fn get_int<'a, T: Foo<'a, Bar=I>, I: Iterator<Item=&'a usize>>(t: T) -> usize {
  t.make()
}
```

That is, you have to specify explicitly that the type of `Bar` is an iterator of the corresponding type. The trait bound inside the trait definition alone is insufficient.

This is very much like regular type parameters work. Even if you write something like

```
trait Parameterized<T: Clone> { ... }
```

You still need to write

```
fn do_something<P: Parameterized<T>, T: Clone>() { ... }
```

Or with structs:

```
struct S<T: Iterator<i32>> { ... }

impl<T: Iterator<i32>> for S<T> { ... }
```

This does look counterintuitive (and I've stumbled upon this several times as well) and probably deserves an issue in [RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs) repo.

Comment: As of Rust 1.4, the code in the question works fine.